# e.Row.Cell adding control does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code:

```
 protected void gvContacts_RowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {       

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = "test";        

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(label);  //doesnt work
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "this works";

        }
    }
}
```

where label does not appear to my cells. What's wrong?

Comment: Where are you attempting to call this code?  Specifically, is it being called in RowDataBind ?

Comment: Where are you writing this code? You can't add controls anywhere. The [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) might be pretty complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create a new instance of your label in each loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
{
   label = new Label();
   label.Text = "test";
   e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(label);
   e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "this works";
}
```

Comment: I figured that out. Any explanation why having one instance does not work?

Comment: Because you are adding the same control on each cell. When you add it to another cell, you are removing it from the last cell, because only exist one object.

Comment: Remember that this type of objects (controls) are ByReference, not ByValue : )

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

- Make sure the `RowType` is actually `DataControlRowType.DataRow`
- Make sure `e.Row.RowIndex == 0`

Set a breakpoint in the code so you can make sure of those values.

After this, it looks like your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got a header row:

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
```

Your row 0 will be of DataControlRowType.HeaderRow

You want != 0, I think

Comment: no, that line is correct. I have a header, but index 0 is one bellow, which I need.

Comment: Then I refer to Adrian's response - debug test it and check the values coming in.  Make sure your gridView is firing the event.

Comment: I cannot remember - does it matter if the fields are defined as template fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add TableCell before adding control:

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();      
e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(label);
```